# How to group fields to get one change value handler

Tags: java, gwt

I have a Presenter like this:

```
public class ItemPresenter {

public interface Display {
TextBox getFilterItemName();
TextBox getFilterItemAmount();
}

public ItemPresenter() {
addChangeValueHandlers();

private void addChangeValueHandlers() {
this.display.getFilterItemName().addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
                display.reload(getItemList(display.getFilterBaseVersionName()
                        .getText()));
            }
        });
this.display.getFilterItemAmount().addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
                display.reload(getItemList(display.getFilterItemAmount()
                        .getText()));
            }
        });
}
}
```

As you see I have filter and each value change on field from filter should invokes a reload(...) method to get fresh data.

It is possible to group field from filter to one group and have an posibility to implement a change handler? Like this:

```
public class ItemPresenter {

public interface Display {
TextBox getFilterItemName();
TextBox getFilterItemAmount();
Filter getFilter();
}

public ItemPresenter() {
addChangeValueHandlers();

private void addChangeValueHandlers() {
this.display.getFilter.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
                display.reload(getItemList(display.getFilterBaseVersionName()
                        .getText(), display.getFilterItemAmount()
                        .getText()));
            }
        });
}
}
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve more or less the same behavior by registering the same handler on both filterItemName and filterItemAmount :

```
ChangeHandler handler = new ChangeHandler() {...}
this.display.getFilterItemAmount().addChangeHandler(handler);
this.display.getFilterItemName().addChangeHandler(handler);
```